# My Galaxy Nexus can't hold on to a signal

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, network-signal

I have an unlocked international-version Galaxy Nexus on the German T-Mobile network.  It's only about a week old, but more than once in that time I've seen the signal drop completely out, and won't come back until I reboot -- and sometimes not even then.  In the same location, my old AT&T Captivate (rooted, running a custom ICS ROM) gets 2-3 bars of signal, around -100dBm.  I've read a lot of Verizon users complaining about the GN's radio, but I haven't heard of people having problems with the International version.

Is this fixable?  Are there newer revisions of the phone where this issue is fixed?  If not, does it vary between individual handsets?  Would exchanging it for an "identical" handset stand a chance of getting better hardware?

Comment: Parts of your question make this off topic and more of a shopping recommendation. - If you have what you think are hardware issues, then i would exchange it for another unit.

Comment: If a factory reset doesn't fix the issue, then it's likely a hardware problem and you should exchange the phone.

Comment: Swapped GNex handsets twice last month for this issue.

Comment: I've tweaked the question.  It should still solicit the info you need and help you make your shopping decision without bringing up the shopping decision :P

Comment: Thanks, Matthew.  I had a similar issue with the Captivate (the GPS, in that case) where some advised swapping out handsets for a better receiver, but I waited too long and got stuck with a bad one.  I want to avoid doing that here.

Comment: There is currently a 4.0.4 update in a phased roll out to GSM Galaxy Nexus's [source](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104629412415657030658/posts/NgGwavbmkQ7), that does apparently have a new radio baseband version in it, this may (or may not) make things more stable.

Comment: @GAThrawn There are multiple reports that the radio in 4.0.4 makes this issue even worse on GSM Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look is like [this is a pretty widespread problem](http://www.engadget.com/2012/04/05/gsm-galaxy-nexus-signal-problem-issue-android-4-0-4/). It doesn't answer my shopping question (should I return it) but at least I can say with confidence that it's not just me, so it should get addressed eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the process is for it being a vanilla developer phone, but I know many Samsung devices can flash a radio package through the Recovery mode, to potentially improve signal and speeds. For the Nexus, there seems to be plenty of dumps available [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1405345) to install which might help your signal problems. 
**Note** however that this is a purely trial-and-error process which can, in some circumstances, cause unforeseen side effects so be careful about it.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but this is my wife's phone -- she specifically doesn't want to (her words) "fiddle with it" and if that ends up being necessary to get a working device, she's just going to return it and probably buy another operating system :/