# Galaxy Nexus going into Airplane mode on its own

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, airplane-mode

Sometimes I will notice that my phone has no signal and if I hold the power button down it will tell me it is in airplane mode.  To fix it I need to reboot the phone.

Clicking the airplane mode option once, waiting and clicking it again will fix it but often not.  While in this mode wi-fi continues to work fine, just connectivity to the phone network is gone.

This is a pain because I could be missing calls etc while this is going on.

If the phone is put into airplane mode by me I get the little plane icon.  This does not happen when it goes into airplane mode on its own.

Comment: From what you described, I don't think it's because the phone is going to airplane mode, it seems more likely that only the 3G connection our the cell connection goes bad and toggling airplane mode causes the phone to try to reconnect to the access point. Without further details, it's hard to figure out what's wrong with your device; best bet is to call your provider's customer service while this is happening from a second phone and ask them if your phone is registered to the cell towers and if they see something abnormal with the connection.

Comment: Might be the same issue is this.  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21376/my-galaxy-nexus-cant-hold-on-to-a-signal